# Can I run 2 separate ranges on the same physical network

Tags: ipv4

My current set up is 1 router and 2 switches, the router being 192.168.10.1 with a connection to each switch then 8 and 10 devices on the 2 switches all 192.168.10.x

I have an NVR with 2 ports, 1 of which is connected to the second switch as 192.168.10.128

The second port is for connection to Cameras/Audio etc and is currently set at 192.168.30.1 with the 6 cameras addressed as 192.168.30.x and connected to a separate PoE switch.

I am wanting to add 2 additional cameras at the far end of the building but cannot cable these direct to the PoE switch, so I am hoping to add another PoE switch for the 2 additional cameras and connect this to the router/switch 1 and connect the other switch to switch 2 so effectively I would have 2 unrelated networks, which do not need to talk to each other running on one physical network.

Would this work or would 2 ranges not talking cause problems?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It sounds like you just need to use VLANs.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run multiple IP subnets on the same Ethernet segment. However, this very rarely makes sense. In your case, I would renumber one subnet when connecting both switches.

DHCP is a convenient way to organize IP addresses. Likely, you'd want to reserve the camera addresses on the DHCP server, so each one keeps its IP address permanently.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The problem I have is that the NVR will not allow camera connections on the main port and will also not allow the 2 ports to be on the same subnet or in the same range, the camera port is the gateway for that range and needs to remain separate, also from a security perspective as I would not want the cameras on the network with internet access

Comment: You might want to consider using VLANs to cleanly partition the camera segments from the rest of the network.

Answer (score 0):

The best and optimised configuration for your requirement is segmentation of network by creating vlans and assign each vlan with each subnet .

As you are using router as perimeter devices configure inter vlan routing in router and connect single physical cable with layer2 switch and configure trunk port allowing all vlan between router and layer2 switch on single physical network . Futher your can control traffic on different Vlan by configuring access-list at router this configuration will ensure restrictions of traffic among different vlàns à per business requirements ..